About the nuance of “over”
I am a Japanese student and learning English.
I have a question about the nuance of “over.”
What is the difference between“I walked him to the classroom”and “I walked him over to the classroom”? What kind of nuance does “over” give to the latter sentence?

Taken literally, over and similar words such as up, down, around, etc would refer to the geography of the route. However these words are not always taken literally. Using over suggests there is something to be crossed, but it may not be anything significant.
These words are often used in conversation to indicate a less formal register, so your second example is less formal than your first.
